# Nvidia HD audio noise reduction

Tags: audio, nvidia

I've recently switched from Realtek motherboard audio to Nvidia HD audio (GTX 1070Ti) and I have noticed that Nvidia HD audio has a noise reduction feature.  I am listening to audio output from my monitor via headphones, the monitor is of course connected via HDMI to the GPU.  I listened to different audio streams and confirmed this.

I can't find a way to turn this off as it seems to be baked in to the digital audio that the GPU sends to the monitor.  The monitor itself has no such audio quality settings, just volume. The Nvidia control panel does not have audio enhancements (or tweaks) settings (just on or off).  This is also not windows sound doing this (as I have also turned off all audio enhancements there).

Messing with Realtek settings would do anything as I'm not using onboard sound devices.  Uninstalling Nvidia HD audio also makes windows not recognize any monitor as a sound outputting device (which I guess means the GPU does not send an audio signal to them?).
Any thoughts would be appreciated.
Thank You.